# Canvas under div blocks jquery event IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a canvas under a div and trying to get a mouseenter event on the div. This works in all other browsers. But when i try it in IE9 it fails. You can see that the canvas is underneath the div but the event is does not fire.

Is there a other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the background to an image and making it transparent. It has to do with the hasLayout property causing issues in IE.